launch ffmpeg on Maui Android
I have an Maui app which is deployed on an Android tablet, a Samsung tab S9 FE.
I have copied the ARM8 version of the ffmpeg executable in the AppDataDirectory of my deployed app. The executable, named "ffmpeg", has the rights _rwxrwxrwx (the underscore means this is a file, and not a directory).
I try to execute the file with the command Process.Start:
private void GetThumbnail(string inputFile, string imageFullPath, string ffmpegFullPath)
{
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        string arguments = $"-i {inputFile} -ss 00:01:00.000 -vframes 1 {imageFullPath}";

        startInfo.FileName = ffmpegFullPath;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.Arguments = arguments;

        try
        {
            Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
            process.WaitForExit(5000);
            process.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
}

There is an exception saying the access is denied:

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (13): An error occurred trying to
start process '/data/user/0/sxb.explorateur.de.fichiers/files/ffmpeg'
with working directory '/data/data/sxb.explorateur.de.fichiers/files'.
Permission denied

The error message doesn't say more, and I do not see what to do, the directory usually is dedicated to the application, and the file is executable.
I know that Android has restricted policies with file execution, and maybe it's even harder for the Samsung operating system, namely One UI 6.1.1 and Android 14.
thank you.

This question is similar to: What path to put executable to run on Android 29?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also be aware of existing Android supported ports of ffmpeg like: https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit
